# macOS Ventura delete removed application icon

Tags: macos, finder, applications, ventura

After uninstalling applications from finder Applications tab the icon of the app won't disappear

[image: games]

How can I remove the icon of an uninstalled app ?

Comment: I would advise you to restart your Mac, that's a thing what worked for me.

Comment: @Thinkr I did but the icon is still there .

Comment: According to this reddit thread, https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/s1ftmi/comment/hs9bla8/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3 it appears you haven't entirely deleted the epic launcher app. So, follow the instructions in the first comment there. If that doesn't work, let me know because it could be that there's still some other files lurking around that's causing it to show